# UISwitch in UINavigationBar functionality

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uiswitch

I have added a UISwitch to my Navigation Controller. This switch controls the underlying tableview and toggles it between 2 data sources. However, when i tried adding IBOutlets and Actions the suggested type came up as UIBarButtonItem, nevertheless when i saved it as a UISwitch, so i could have the .on boolean. However, it seems that the switch is not doing anything. When i click it nothing is happening and Im not sure as to why. My code below.

```
@IBAction func PreferencesToggled(sender: UIButton) {
        if DataToggle.on
        {
            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            if let prefs = defaults.objectForKey("teachPref"){
                data = prefs as! [newsarticle]
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            else{
                data = [newsarticle]()
                data.append(newsarticle(name: "No Teachers Saved",desc: "http://www.google.com"))
            }
            let footer = UIView()
            self.tableView.tableFooterView = footer
        }
        else{
            self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil
            getdata()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to create a UIBarButtonItem with initWithCustomView and add your switch as a subview of the button. I don't think you can do that using only interface builder though.

Comment: How do i create a blank UIBarButton? Or do i just overlap the switch on top of the pre-existing one?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, was offline during the weekend. I Hope you have figured it out by now, but if not, I'm posting the code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to add a switch programmatically to your navigtion bar:

```
    let switchView = UISwitch()
    switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.PreferencesToggled(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    //customize your switch here
    let barBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: switchView)
    self.navBar?.topItem?.setRightBarButtonItem(barBtn, animated: false)
```